# Programmatically Add Control To DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I am trying to find the last row of my grid, and programmatically add a drop down list to the grid.  My code compiles with no issues, but my `RowDataBound` is never hit when stepping through the code causing the list to never be added.  What have I improperly coded?

**EDIT**
The page loads and you select an option from the drop down list. RefreshdatagridTest is called at that point.

**End Of Edit**

**ASP Code**

```
<div class="CenterGrid">
    <asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="datagridTest" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
Width="500px" CssClass="DataGrids" HorizontalAlign="Center" GridLines="Both"
ShowFooter="true"     OnSelectedIndexChanged="datagridTest_SelectedIndexChanged" 
OnItemCommand="datagridTest_ItemCommand" RowDataBound="datagridTest_RowDataBound" Visible="true">
        <ItemStyle CssClass="row" />
        <FooterStyle CssClass="DataGridFooters" />
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="DataGridHeaders" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Firefly" HeaderText="Name"></asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:ButtonColumn CommandName="Delete" HeaderText="Delete From List" Text="[Remove]"></asp:ButtonColumn>
        </Columns>
    </asp:DataGrid>
</div>
```

**C# Code**

```
protected void datagridTest_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowIndex == datagridTest.Items.Count - 1)
  {
    DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
    e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(ddl);
  }
}

protected void datagridTest_ItemCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
  LinkButton lnkbtn = ((LinkButton)e.CommandSource);
  if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
  {
    DataGridItem deletecontrol = (DataGridItem)lnkbtn.NamingContainer;
    string bomb = deletecontrol.Cells[0].Text;
    RemoveFireflyFromList(bomb);
    RefreshdatagridTest();
  }
}
```

**How the grid gets data bound**

```
protected void listselect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  RefreshdatagridTest();
}


private void RefreshdatagridTest()
{
  dataSet = Run sql procedure to get results;
  this.datagridTest.DataSource = dataSet;
  this.datagridTest.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Are you actually binding the grid to a datasource?  Please add that code as well.

Comment: Is `RefreshdatagridTest` getting called when you step through?

Comment: @EdT - The page loads and you select an option from the drop down list.  RefreshdatagridTest is called at that point.

Answer (score 0):

its bit differente since in my exemple i generate new row at runtime but basicaly its how it work;
in my case had to add some size param or control was hidden.
so i just get to set control row's and add the row to the grid.

```
Mycontrol m = new Mycontrol();
     RowDefinition rowDef1 = new RowDefinition();

                rowDef1.MaxHeight = m.ExpandedSise;
                rowDef1.MinHeight = m.Height;
                rowDef1.Height = new GridLength(m.RowDefColapsedSize);
                int rownumber = grid2.RowDefinitions.Count;
                grid2.RowDefinitions.Insert(rownumber, rowDef1);
                Grid.SetRow(m, rownumber);
                m.counter.Content = Grid.GetRow(m).ToString();
                grid2.Children.Add(m);
```

Comment: Since my 'RowDataBound' method isn't being called what would be the proper method to add this syntax to so it executes?

Comment: it looks like RowDefinition is used for Windows.Control.  This is a Web project.